# Не отображается ValidationError Django 3

Tags: python, django

Вообщем логика такая.

Есть товар на главной странице с какой-либо информацией, а также небольшая форма, которая возвращает количество этого товара.
Проблема в том, что когда форма попадает в представление всё работает вроде корректно, но когда проходит проверка на валидацию формы и она возвращает false, то по-идеи должно вызываться исключение ValidationError, определённое мной, но оно просто игнорируется, но само условие, которое вызывает исключение работает правильно и новый объект не создаётся.

Вообщем вся логика работает корректно, за исключением того, что не отображается сообщение определённое в ValidationError.

**Файл forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import * 

class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['qty']

    def clean_qty(self): 
        if self.cleaned_data['qty'] > 20 or self.cleaned_data['qty'] < 1:
            raise ValidationError('Error')

        return self.cleaned_data['qty']
```

**Файл views.py**

```
def index(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    form = CartForm()

    context = {
        'all_products': all_products,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'shop/catalog.html', context)

@require_POST
def add_to_cart(request, prod_id: int):

    form = CartForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        customer = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=prod_id)

        new_product = Cart.objects.create(
            product_id=product, 
            customer_id=customer,
            qty=form.cleaned_data['qty'])

        new_product.save()
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

**Форма в шаблоне**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_to_cart_url' prod.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Добавить в корзину</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо рейза ошибки нужно использовать `add_error`

```
self.add_error("qty", "Error")
```

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, ситуация та же, обработка условия работает правильно - сообщения об ошибки нету.

Comment: а как смотрите ошибку?

Comment: что в `form.errors`?

Comment: Блок ошибок в шаблоне я вообще не добавляю.

У меня во втором приложении логика для регистрации юзера, метод clean_ описан точно также, только на проверку мыла, таким же образом вызывал исключение - всё работает, но сделал для количества там чёт не пашет.